# How to fix a lost variable due to inheritance?

Tags: c#

I have a code that uses inheritance in C# and I seem to have lost my price variable along the way. How can I get my price variable to work with the child classes when the parent class doesn't have it as a parameter? Please note: this has been submitted and marked, I'm not looking for extra marks, just trying to improve my learning.

Not sure if this is enough code to help, but I didn't want to flood the screen. Basically the PerformBuyStock method is in the program file and it records the price variable along with the quantity. However once the transaction is executed through the transaction class, because it doesn't have 3 parameters (stock, price, quantity) like the StockPurchaseTransaction class, then the price reverts to 0 when it executes printSummary. How do I get the price variable to still be there without changing the Transaction class? Thank you for any help you may be able to provide.

```
public abstract class Transaction
{
    protected readonly Stock _stock;
    protected readonly decimal _price;
    protected readonly int _quantity;
    protected readonly string SummaryLine;


    public Transaction(Stock stock, int quantity)
    {
        _quantity = quantity;
        _stock = stock;

       SummaryLine = ($" - {_stock.Name} x {_quantity} @${_price}");
    }
}


public class StockPurchaseTransaction : Transaction
{


    public StockPurchaseTransaction(Stock stock, decimal price, int quantity) :base(stock, quantity)
    {
        stock = _stock;
        price = _price;
        quantity = _quantity;
    }
    public override void PrintSummary()
    {

        Console.WriteLine($"BUY {SummaryLine}");


    }
}

private static void PerformBuyStock(Warehouse toWarehouse)
    {   
        Stock stock = FindStockItem(toWarehouse);
        if (stock == null) return;
        int quantity;
        decimal price;

        Console.WriteLine($"Quantity of {stock.Name} purchased:");
        quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine($"Price per item purchased: ");
        price = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

        StockPurchaseTransaction purchase;
        purchase = new StockPurchaseTransaction(stock, price, quantity);


        toWarehouse.ExecuteTransaction(purchase);
        purchase.PrintSummary();

    }


public void ExecuteTransaction(Transaction transaction)
    {
        _transactions.Add(transaction);
        transaction.Execute();
    }
```

Comment: Would you be allowed to change `protected readonly decimal _price;` to `abstract protected decimal price { get; };`?

Comment: Can you talk us through what you are trying to achieve by `stock = _stock;
        price = _price;
        quantity = _quantity;`? It seems odd to set the **parameter** values like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the price reverts to 0 when it executes printSummary. How do I get the price variable to still be there without changing the Transaction class?

The issue is that the base class constructor is what sets the `SummaryLine` field, which is used to print the summary later. But at the time that that field is set, the `_price` field hasn't been initialized to the caller-provided value (indeed, it never is). It still has the default value of `0`.

It certainly doesn't help that in the subclass constructor, you aren't even assigning the field correctly. The variables are on the wrong side of each assignment operator. As it happens, if you'd put them on the correct side, you'd have gotten a helpful compile-time error message explaining that the subclass constructor isn't allowed to assign a value to the `readonly` fields in the base class.

Anyway…

To fix it without changing the `Transaction` class? Well, the only way to do that is to add code in your subclass `StockPurchaseTransaction` that mirrors the code in the base class, but fixes the bugs that exist in it.

That might look something like this:

```cs
public StockPurchaseTransaction(Stock stock, decimal price, int quantity) :base(stock, quantity)
{
    // To be clear: these three assignments are incorrect, and accomplish nothing
    stock = _stock;
    price = _price;
    quantity = _quantity;

    // This assignment would "fix" the problem, but it's not really the right way,
    // and the field is readonly so this won't actually compile
    SummaryLine = ($" - {stock.Name} x {quantity} @${price}");
}
```

Except that won't work, because unlike the assignments before it, the correct assignment of `SummaryLine` won't work as long as the base class field is `readonly`.

But really, the base class constructor is what's wrong, and that's where the fix ought to go:

```cs
public Transaction(Stock stock, int quantity, decimal price)
{
    _quantity = quantity;
    _stock = stock;
    _price = price;

   SummaryLine = ($" - {_stock.Name} x {_quantity} @${_price}");
}
```

Of course, then you'd need to add the `price` parameter to the base class constructor call:

```cs
public StockPurchaseTransaction(Stock stock, decimal price, int quantity)
    : base(stock, quantity, price) { }
```

Note that if you do it that way, then the subclass constructor has nothing to do. All of the real work is done in the base class.

Bottom line, it's impossible to do what you are literally asking. The base class has bugs in it, and because of the `readonly` fields, you can't correct for those bugs in the subclass. They have to be fixed in the base class.

Comment: Thanks. I've always thought it was odd that they put restrictions on changing certain things. This is very helpful in improving my coding.

Comment: I'm glad you added that comment on the assignments. I was wondering if that was a mistake and I had to read very carefully to know that you intended to do that.

Comment: @madreflection: yeah, it took me a little bit to figure out the best way to present that. It's confusing, but I tried to stick as closely to the original code and change only what was needed, because of the requirement to not change the base class.

Comment: I think the requirement of "without changing the Transaction class" might have been self-imposed. If it wasn't, e.g. if the class was provided by the instructor and expected not to be touched, I would have to ding the professor for the mistake.

Comment: @madreflection: the OP has commented above that they've _"...always thought it was odd that they put restrictions on changing certain things"_. I infer from that, that the requirement to not change the `Transaction` class was imposed as part of the assignment. It is possible that the student (the OP) has transcribed the provided class incorrectly, or that the OP wrote it and the assignment requires them to refrain from backtracking even if it creates hardship (as it would here), or that the author of the assignment has themselves made a mistake. Not possible to know from this far away. :)

Comment: Oh, the comment. Yes. I interpreted that as the compiler putting restrictions on assignments; as you pointed out, you can't assign `_price` in the subclass because it's `readonly` in the base class. My mistake.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your feedback. Because this is now just for my learning, I have gone with everyone's comments (and my gut) and changed the Transaction class to include price, which is working very well. I have no idea why they said not to change it.